# How to answer the ssh-keygen passphrase prompt from Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

In Python, I would like to verify a pair of public/private keys which have a passphrase by command `ssh-keygen -y -f`. The code is as below,

```
#/usr/bin/env python3
...................
...................
command = "ssh-keygen -y -f {}".format(key1)
args = bytes("%s\n%s\n" % (psw, psw), encoding='utf8')
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate(input=args)
```

I thought `subprocess.communicate(input=args)` could answer the prompt with passphrase.

But I still got the prompt for password.

Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh-keygen` has [`-P` switch](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen#P) to provide a passphrase:

```
command = "ssh-keygen -y -f {} -P \"{}\"".format(key1, passphrase)
```

It's ok to use an empty passphrase (`-P ""`), when the key is not encrypted.

And if you use a wrong/empty passphrase (`-P "wrong"`), for an encrypted key, `ssh-keygen` will fail – it won't prompt you for a good passphrase again.